# Rails getting error installing sharetribe undefined method `dump'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, sharetribe

I am trying to install sharetribe from [Github](https://github.com/BruhKofi/twaho)

I followed from the start and installed all prerequisites.
When executing the command the build failed with:

NoMethodError: undefined method `dump' for #MessagePack::Factory:0x00007fcf4f984a38
Did you mean?  dup

trace

bundle exec rake db:create db:structure:load --trace   /Users/david/sharetribe/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/yaml.rb:46:in `install!'  /Users/david/sharetribe/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache.rb:20:in` setup'
/Users/david/sharetribe/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:69:in `setup' /Users/david/sharetribe/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:110:in` default_setup'
/Users/david/sharetribe/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:4:in `<top (required)>' /Users/david/sharetribe/config/boot.rb:4:in` require'
/Users/david/sharetribe/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>' /Users/david/sharetribe/config/application.rb:3:in` require_relative'
/Users/david/sharetribe/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>' /Users/david/sharetribe/Rakefile:4:in` require'
/Users/david/sharetribe/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>' /Users/david/sharetribe/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in` load'
/Users/david/sharetribe/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile' /Users/david/sharetribe/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in` raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/david/sharetribe/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile' /Users/david/sharetribe/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in` standard_exception_handling'
/Users/david/sharetribe/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile' /Users/david/sharetribe/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in` block in run'
/Users/david/sharetribe/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling' /Users/david/sharetribe/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in` run'
/Users/david/sharetribe/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>' /Users/david/sharetribe/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/rake:23:in` load'
/Users/david/sharetribe/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>' /Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in` load'
/Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load' /Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in` run'
/Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/cli.rb:494:in `exec' /Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in` run'
/Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command' /Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in` dispatch'
/Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch' /Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in` start'
/Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start' /Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/exe/bundle:49:in` block in <top (required)>'
/Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:130:in `with_friendly_errors' /Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/exe/bundle:37:in` <top (required)>'
/Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/bundle:23:in `load'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bootsnap version 1.4.5 worked for me.
You have to update your gemfile for an exact version though, since
`gem 'bootsnap', '~> 1.4.5', require: false`
will update you to 1.4.9.
Use
`gem 'bootsnap', '1.4.5', require: false`
instead.

Comment: Looks like an answer now. Thanks. Would you like to explain the subtle difference between `'~> 1.4.5'` and `'1.4.5'` and how/why it prevents/achieves solution? (Asking/proposing as one with zero technical knowledge.)

Comment: What is the meaning of adding “~>”?

Comment: I'm new to Ruby so don't quote me, but from what it looks like, it means the latest minor version.  So if you use '~> 1.4.5' and the latest minor version is 1.4.9, after which comes 1.5.0.  It will use 1.4.9.